# SBT task dependsOn

Tags: sbt

Since SBT 0.13.13 this is deprecated (`<<=` is deprecated):

```scala
compile in Compile <<= (compile in Compile).dependsOn(apiDoc)
```

So the only way to do I found is this:

```scala
compile in Compile := {
  apiDoc.value
  (compile in Compile).value
}
```

But now I have a warning about a useless expression `apiDoc.value`.
But this is not useless!
I can't find any documentation about what is the new way to do.

Comment: Is there any difference in the outcome of {...} and dependsOn?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I haven't found docs for this, but you can create a `dependsOn` like:

```scala
compile.in(Compile) := compile.dependsOn(apiDoc).value
```

Note that if you're doing this for an `InputTask`, you'll need to use `evaluated` instead of `value`:

```
myInputTask := myInputTask.dependsOn(apiDoc).evaluated
```

Comment: As of sbt `1.1.1`, this approach now works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44669226/1080804

Answer (score 2):

I've struggled with the problem of depending tasks and it all became clear after I read this page: http://www.beyondthelines.net/computing/understanding-sbt/

TLD;DR: to make a task dependent on another inside a task definition, you have to use `Def.sequential` (examples from the page):

```
lazy val A = taskKey[Unit]("Task A")
A in Global := { println("Task A") }
 
lazy val B = taskKey[Unit]("Task B")
B in Global := { println("Task B") }
 
lazy val C = taskKey[Unit]("Task C")
C := Def.sequential(A, B).value
```

So for your case, it would be:

```
compile in Compile := Def.sequential(apiDoc, compile in Compile).value
```

Or, if you use the new sbt syntax and have different scoping:

```
ThisBuild / Compile / compile := Def.sequential(apiDoc, Compile / compile).value
```