# SBT 0.13/1.0 - replacment for <<= / <+= operators to redefine tasks?

Tags: scala, sbt

Currently SBT tells me that `<<=` I'm using to add a trigger certain events is deprecated.

`updateBrowsers <<= updateBrowsers.triggeredBy(fastOptJS in Compile)`

It suggests using `:=` or `~=` instead.

However after several attempts, `fastOptJS` no longer triggers the `updateBrowsers` task.

What I've tried:

```
updateBrowsers := updateBrowsers.triggeredBy(fastOptJS in Compile)

updateBrowsers ~= (_ => updateBrowsers.triggeredBy(fastOptJS in Compile))

updateBrowsers :=  Def.task {
  updateBrowsers.triggeredBy(fastOptJS in Compile)
}

updateBrowsers := Def.taskDyn {
  updateBrowsers.triggeredBy(fastOptJS in Compile)
}
```

So, how do we add need task dependencies or task triggers in SBT 0.13+?

Comment: If a `dependsOn` rephrasing works, you can try the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41183255/sbt-task-dependson/41190904#41190904). I can't get `triggeredBy` to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your answer is in the docs

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Migrating-from-sbt-012x.html#Migrating+when+using+%2C++or

It states it clearly that if you have:

```
a <<= a triggeredBy b
```

You CANNOT replace it with an `:=` in SBT 0.13.13 and earlier due to issue [#1444](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1444).

Comment: Ah thanks - I missed it while reading it originally. Will accept the answer after confirming that the a new version no longer has this issue