# Migrating task dependencies from <<= to :=

Tags: sbt

In SBT 0.13

```
docker <<= docker dependsOn assembly
```

gives a deprecation warning. Instead the `:=` operator is recommended.

```
docker := {
  assembly.value
  docker.value
}
```

Does not work, because order of execution is not guaranteed. I need these two tasks to run in serial.

What's the trick?

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41183255/sbt-task-dependson/41190904. See the answer there. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SBT task dependsOn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41183255/sbt-task-dependson)

Comment: Thanks. There are too many questions about sbt task dependencies that predate 0.13 for your previous answer to appear in searches.

Answer (score -1):

```
dockerfile in docker := {

  val artifact: File = assembly.value
  val artifactTargetPath = (assemblyOutputPath in assembly).value

  new Dockerfile {
    from("java:8-jre")
    add(artifact, artifactTargetPath)
```