# How to force task dependency in SBT

Tags: sbt, integration-testing, publish

I have a project built with SBT 0.13, and I publish it using the `publishSigned` task. How do I force this task to depend on the integration test task, so that integration tests will automatically run before publishing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SBT task dependsOn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41183255/sbt-task-dependson)

Comment: No, as I can't find in which scope or configuration `publishSigned` is defined

Comment: Have you tried `publishSigned := publishSigned.dependsOn(test in IntegrationTest).value`?